# Script for sending funds to a multisig address

Tags: development, multi-signature

Does sending funds **to** a multisig address require different script than the one used for ordinary addresses? If yes, how should this script look like? (Under multisig address I mean Bitcoin script hash which starts with 3 instead of 1).

I write a bitcoin library in Scala for research purposes which can be found here: https://github.com/ahahaebat/BitScala. Current code creates correct transactions for ordinary addresses but fails to do so for multisig ones.

Currently the script is the same for both types of addresses:
OP_DUP, OP_HASH160, address_hash, OP_EQUALVERIFY, OP_CHECKSIG

Should I change it somehow for multisig addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Script for P2SH should be:

```
OP_HASH160, address_hash, OP_EQUAL
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Could you please elaborate why this script is required for P2SH or perhaps point out to some links on the matter?

Comment: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0016.mediawiki and everything else about bip-16